# While send image from jsp file to jquery ajax its shows me [object FormData]. Its only for image value. How to solve It?

Tags: html, jquery, jsp

Here my jquery code:

```
function addstaffdetail()
{
var isFormValid = true;
$(document).ready(function() {
    
$(".modal-body input,select").each(function(){
    if (($(this).val()).length == 0){
        $(this).addClass("highlight");
        isFormValid = false;
        $(this).focus();
    }
    else{
        $(this).removeClass("highlight");
        }
    });
if (!isFormValid) { 
    alert("Please fill in all the required fields (indicated by *)");
}
else{
       var staffrole=$("#facultyrole").val();
         var department=$("#dept").val();
        var fname=$("#fname").val();
    
        var data;

        data = new FormData();
        data.append( 'file', $( '#fimage' )[0].files[0] );
        
    
        
        var qualification=$("#qualification").val();
        var dob=$("#dob").val();
        var gender=$("#gender").val();
        var religion=$("#religion").val();
        var fathername=$("#fathername").val();
        var mothername=$("#mothername").val();
        var address=$("#address").val();
        var contactno=$("#contactno").val();
        var email=$("#email").val();
        var aatharno=$("#aatharno").val();
        var pan=$("#pan").val();
        var description=$("#description").val();
       var sta=$("#selectstatus").val();
      var dataString="role="+staffrole+"&department="+department+"&facname="+fname+"" +
            "&fimage="+data+"&qualification="+qualification+"&date="+dob+
            "&gender="+gender+"&fathername="+fathername+"&mothername="+mothername+
            "&address="+address+"&contactno="+contactno+"&email="+email+
            "&religion="+religion+"&aadhar="+aatharno+"&pan="+pan+"&comment="+description+"&status="+sta;
       
      
            console.log(dataString);
       
    $.ajax({
       type:"POST",
        url:"AddFacultyBasicDetails",
        data: dataString,
        processData: false,
        success: function(data){
        $('.content-wrapper').html(data);
   }
 });
}
});
return true;
 }
```

Here my html code:

```
<div id="addstaffdetails-modal" class="modal fade" id="modal-default" data-backdrop="false" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
          <div class="modal-content">
            <form method="post" action="" id="uploadForm" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <div class="modal-header">
              <h4 class="modal-title">Add Staff's Basic details</h4>
              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
              <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
              </button>
            </div>
           
            <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="facultyrole">Faculty Role</label>
                        <select class="form-control" id="facultyrole" required>
                        <option value="">Select Any One</option>
                         <% TeachStaffService ss=new TeachStaffService();
                                List<TeachStaffBean> ll=ss.getTeachStaffList();
                                            Iterator<TeachStaffBean> ir1=ll.iterator();
                        while(ir1.hasNext())
                        {
                            TeachStaffBean sb=(TeachStaffBean)ir1.next();
                        
                            %>
                            <option value="<%= sb.getTeachid()%>" > <%= sb.getType() %></option>
                            
                            <% }
                            %>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="dept">Department</label>
                        <select class="form-control" id="dept" required>
                        <option value="">Select Any One</option>
                          <% DepartmentService ds=new DepartmentService();
                                List<DepartmentsBean> db=ds.getDepartmentList();
                                            Iterator<DepartmentsBean> id=db.iterator();
                        while(id.hasNext())
                        {
                            DepartmentsBean deb=(DepartmentsBean)id.next();
                        
                            %>
                            <option value="<%= deb.getDepid()%>" > <%= deb.getAbbrevation() %></option>
                            
                            <% }
                            %>
                        </select>
                    </div>
            
                    <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="fname">Faculty Name</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="fname" name="fname" placeholder="Faculty Name" maxlength="29" title="Enter Faculty Name without salutation" placeholder="Faculty Name" required value="">
                    </div>
                  
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="fimage">Faculty image</label>
                    <input type="file" class="form-control" id="fimage" name="fimage" title="Enter Faculty image. File size must be maximum 65 kb">
                    </div>
                  
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="fname">Qualification</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="qualification" name="qualification" placeholder="B.Sc., M.Sc., Ph. D." maxlength="39" title="Enter Qualification Ph. D. without -" placeholder="Ph. D." required value="">
                    </div>
                  
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="dob">DOB</label>
                    <input type="date" class="form-control" id="dob" name="dob" title="Enter staff DOB" required value="">
                    </div>
                    
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="gender">Gender</label>
                        <select class="form-control" id="gender" required>
                        <option value="">Select Any One</option>
                         <option value="male">Male</option>
                         <option value="female">Female</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="religion">Religion</label>
                        <select class="form-control" id="religion" required>
                        <option value="">Select Any One</option>
                         <option value="hindu">Hindu</option>
                         <option value="muslim">Muslim</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="fathername">Father Name</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="fathername" name="fathername" title="Enter staff's Father Name" maxlength="29" placeholder="staff's father name" required value="">
                    </div>
                  
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="mothername">Mother Name</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="mothername" name="mothername" title="Enter staff's Mother Name" maxlength="29" placeholder="staff's mother name" required value="">
                    </div>
                  
                    <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="address">Address</label>
                    <textarea class="form-control" rows="3" id="address" name="address"  placeholder="Enter Address" maxlength="190" title="Enter Address" required></textarea>
                    </div>
                  
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="contactno">Mobile No.</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="contactno" name="contactno" onkeypress="return event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57" onpaste="return false" placeholder="Enter No. only" title="Enter faculty phone no" maxlength="10" required value="">
                    </div>
                    
                    <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="email">Email ID.</label>
                    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" title="Enter staff's Email Id" maxlength="39" placeholder="staff's Email Id" required value="">
                    </div>
                    
                    <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="aatharno">Aathar No.</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="aatharno" name="aatharno" onkeypress="return event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57" onpaste="return false" placeholder="Enter No. only" title="Enter faculty Aathar no" maxlength="12" required value="">
                    </div>
                  
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="pan">PAN</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="pan" name="pan" placeholder="Enter PAN no." title="Enter faculty PAN no" maxlength="10" required value="">
                    </div>
                  
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="description">Description</label>
                    <textarea class="form-control" rows="3" id="description" name="description"  maxlength="49" title="Enter description like his joining date" required></textarea>
                    </div>
                  
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Status</label>
                        <select class="form-control" id="selectstatus" required>
                        <option value="">Select Any One</option>
                          <option value="active">Active</option>
                          <option value="inactive">In-active</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
             </div>
             
            <div class="modal-footer justify-content-between">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
              <input type="button" id="addstaffdetailbtn" class="btn btn-primary" value="Add" id="add_staffdetail" onclick="addstaffdetail()">
            </div> 
             </form>
             </div>
             
            </div>
          </div>
```

Here my console log output values are
[image: Console log file]

How to solve this "Kindly check console log value of fimage. Its return [object FormData]. How to solve this.
My concept was send image from html to mysql via Jquery ajax using Servlet concept.
Here with I added part of HTML code and jquery code.
Am using bootstrap 4 version.

Comment: When you see `[object XX]` it means you've attempted to convert an object to a string.  specifically in your case: `var dataString=..."&fimage="+data+`  - you need that `data` to be a valid string in the first place, not an object.  Try `"&fimage="+JSON.stringify(data)+`.  But depends on how your back-end will accept this, which I can't answer, so not a full answer.

Comment: Note also your console is telling you that your `<script>` tags are not in the correct order (jquery must be before jquery-ui.js) - if you're using bootstrap, then you probably don't want jquery-ui at all as they can conflict.

Comment: @freedomn-m after add this JSON.stringify(data) it shows on console.log output is {} empty braces. how to solve this?